# adding a new has_many relationship to an existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, has-many

I would like to add a has_many relationship to two existing tables/models in my app & I'm not too sure how to di it?

When I did this before with a new model the rails generate command handled everything for me, with just `rails generate model Photo image:string hikingtrail:references` it created the below migration

```
class CreatePhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :photos do |t|
      t.string :image
      t.references :hikingtrail

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :photos, :hikingtrail_id
  end
end
```

Now I would like set up a relationship between `users` & `photos` with each `user` `has_many :photos`.

When I generate a migration to achieve this it does not include the `add_index :photos, :user_id`, is this something I should be doing manually or are the below steps enough for setting up this relationship in my database?

`rails g migration AddUserIdToPhotos user_id:integer`

which creates...

```
class AddUserIdToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :photos, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

& then run...

rake db:migrate

Comment: Hi rossmc - Either you can add the line
   add_index :photos, :user_id
manually in above migration or you can do what zippie has suggested. But in that case also you will have to write that line manually. Thanks Vikram

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is enough to set up your relationship. You can add a index to improve the speed of your record searching. In fact some recommend to put a index to all the foreign keys. But don't worry about this now, i guess you are not going to have that many records to use a index.

If you have already migrated everything and want to add a index make do:

```
 rails g migration AddIndexToUserIdToPhotos
```

and inside add the index column:

```
class AddUserIdToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :photos, :user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks zippie, that looks to have updated my `db/schema.rb` file correctly & I understand it better too :)